# How to use `as` function in styled-components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I'm trying to style a link with styled-components. Depending on props, it will show a `<button>` or a `<Link>`. I saw that I could use the function `as`, but when I do it does not display the `href` in the generated link. Does someone has a solution?

```
const Button = styled.button`
    ...styles
`;


<Button href={props.url} as={props.url ? Link : "button"}>
    {props.children}
</Button>
```

```
<Button>Button without url</Button>
<Button url="/">Button with url</Button>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can do :

If the url is not there, it will stay as button else an anchor tag

```
<Button href={props.url || # } as={props.url && "a" }>
      {props.children}
</Button>
```

Comment: Yes, but I would like to have a router `<Link>` and not an `<a>` tag

Comment: Is Link a styled component or a custom from react-router?

Comment: It's the basic one from react-router

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use [this](https://github.com/kripod/react-polymorphic-box) to achieve what you want.
Than you can simply write this :

```
 <Box as={props.url? Link : Button} to={props.url}>About</Box>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers, I did this solution and it works now:

```
<Container as={props.url && Link} to={props.url} href={props.ext && props.url}>
    {props.children}
</Container>
```